# Basic HTML - applying div id

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

```
 NSString *HTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                      "<head> \n"
                       "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;\">"
                      "<div id='main' style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                      "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@; color:rgb(30,30,30); line-height: %ipx;}\n"
                      "</div> \n"
                      "</head> \n"
                      "<body>%@</body> \n"
                      "</html>", @"helvetica", [NSNumber numberWithInt:[UIFont mainTextFont].pointSize], kWebViewLineSpacing, text];
```

I'm trying to apply a div id `main` to my content, but I can't figure out how to get it to work. I think the line in question is : "`<div id='main' style type=\"text/css\"> \n"` but I'm not sure how I would adjust it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting a div in the head section, that'll not work

```
NSString *HTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                  "<head> \n"
                   "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;\">"
                  "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                  "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@; color:rgb(30,30,30); line-height: %ipx; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; text-overflow: ellipsis; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; overflow: hidden;}\n"
                  "</style> \n"
                  "</head> \n"
                  "<body><div id=\"main\">My main div</div></body> \n"
                  "</html>", @"helvetica", [NSNumber numberWithInt:[UIFont mainTextFont].pointSize], kWebViewLineSpacing, text];
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing things together, you want something more like

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                      "<head> \n"
                       "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;\">"
                      "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                      "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@; color:rgb(30,30,30); line-height: %ipx;}\n"
                      "</style> \n"
                      "</head> \n"
                      "<body><div id='main'>%@</div></body> \n"
                      "</html>", @"helvetica", [NSNumber numberWithInt:[UIFont mainTextFont].pointSize], kWebViewLineSpacing, text];
```

Answer (score 1):

That line doesn't mean anything.  I believe you meant:

```
"<div id='main'><style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
```

Answer (score 0):

div is not valid as a child of head.  It should be a child of body